# How to change an entity's item value?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to summon a mob with a specific value, for example, I want to summon a zombie that had a RED concrete, but when I don't write the value, he spawns with a white concrete. So how can I summon him? This is on Minecraft Java 1.12.2.

Answer (score -2):

The number after the block concrete is the value

- 0 or none=white
- 1=Orange
- 2=magenta
- 3=light blue
- 4=yellow
- 5=lime green
- 6=pink
- 7=dark gray
- 8=light gray
- 9=cyan
- 10=purple
- 11=blue
- 12=brown
- 13=green
- 14=red
- 15=black

This also applies for wood,dye,buckets filled,leather armor(colored),etc...

Comment: Perhaps you could write out the full command for summoning the zombie holding a red concrete?